# Understanding some notation in one-dimensional electron gas

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory

I am a little confused about some notation used in Altland and Simons (second edition) pg 176. In their discussion on the one-dimensional electron gas, they define bosonic operators:

$$b(x) \equiv \left(\frac{k_F}{\pi} + \hat{\rho}(x) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{i \hat{\varphi}\, (x)} \; $$

$$b^\dagger(x) \equiv e^{-i \hat{\varphi}\, (x)} \, \left(\frac{k_F}{\pi} + \hat{\rho}(x) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \; $$

and say $\hat{\varphi}$ describes the phase of the Bose excitations.

Is there an explicit definition of $\hat{\varphi}$ in terms of other variables, or a longer explanation of where $\hat{\varphi}$ comes from? For example $\hat{\rho}$ was discussed previously in section 2.2, but $\hat{\varphi}$ seems to have come out of nowhere.